# How to change style set for multiple Word files quickly?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Using the style set we can quickly set style(**s**) for ONE .docx Ms Word file.

I have tens of such files need to be set to new style. How can I do that quickly without having to open each file manually?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could probably use MACROS, Like these two links: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421500/word-2003-how-to-use-a-macro-to-change-styles
 ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748240/how-can-i-replace-a-microsoft-word-character-style-within-a-range-selection-in-v